# Populating a Data Warehouse from OLTP Relational Database

Tags: database, constraints, database-schema, etl, data-warehouse

I have never done a conversion from a relational database to a data warehouse before. I have the data warehouse tables and models created and am currently creating staging tables. How do I go about actually populating the data warehouse tables? For instance, I am populating a portion of a fact table. However, a primary key cannot contain any null data, so I violate that constraint by transferring data over. I'm assuming primary and foreign key constraints are created prior to migration. Is this correct? Any help is a appreciated, I may be missing some simple database logic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove constraint while you waiting for some data or remove it at all and add it only in daily tests to be sure that data valid.